# Register plugin with kong running in a separate pod

Tags: go, kubernetes, plugins, kong

I'm trying to figure how I could add a plugin (golang) to kong (CE, db-less) when running in Kubernetes.

I want to achieve, that plugins could be real microservices that do not have to be injected into kong container and that do not require a restart of kong to add/update/delete them.

I started exploring the go-pluginserver which now is declared deprecated as a "proxy" I could inject and load plugins to at runtime.

Did anyone achieve this? Is it possible at all? Are there tutorials you know of?